# How to display a span on hover over a circle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made an simple website:
[image: screenshot of website]

My problem is that I want the gray `span#te1` and purple `span#tre1` to open when the user hovers on the little circles `span#punkt1`.

I am looking for a solution with CSS3 or jQuery.  Also it would be nice if the process had a little delay.

My html:

```
<span id="tre1"></span>
<span id="te1"></span>
<span id="punkt1"></span>
```

My CSS:

```
#tre1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 61.5%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #CCC;
    border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

#te1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 205px;
    left: 61.5%;
    background-color: #939;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

#punkt1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 60%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #4ec461;
}
```

Comment: Place the circle element before the other two, and then use the general sibling combinator `~` to make them show up when the circle is hovered: `#punkt1:hover ~ #te1, #punkt1:hover ~ #tre1 { … }`

Comment: For your cirlce elements you should be using a class instead of an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep #tre1 and #te1 in a separate span like this,

```
<span class="punkt1">
    <span id="tre1"></span>
    <span id="te1"></span>
</span>
```

and then do this

```
$("#punkt1").hover(function () {
    $(".punkt1").show(600);
}, function () {
    $(".punkt1").hide(600);
})
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/H262h/1/)

**UPDATE:**

Yes, you can add a `.delay()` before you `.hide()`

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/H262h/4/)

Comment: is it possible that also the triangle slidesup, down?

Comment: @EmSta Well, it doesn't have a `width` and `height`, hence it can't

Comment: @EmSta I have updated my answer to make it look better however

Comment: can it be possible in only CSS

Comment: @badZoke you have the right answer! But one more thing! Is it possible that it does not disspear immediately, but stays there for 3 seconds? I hope you understand wht i mean?

Answer (score 2):

considering you have all the required CSS for the little cricles and grey ,purple image..use `hover()` ..

```
 $(function(){
   $('#te1,#tre1').hide();
   $('#punkt1').hover(function(){
      $('#te1,#tre1').show('slow');
   },function(){
      $('#te1,#tre1').hide('slow');
   });
 });
```

with bit of animation

```
 $('#te1,#tre1').stop().slideDown('slow'); //<--to show;
  $('#te1,#tre1').stop().slideUp('slow'); //<--to hide;
```

[example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/H262h/2/)

**however make sure you have single element with a same id.. Id should always be unique.it looks like you have multile element( little circles) with same id..**